# Pyramid - apache + mod_wsgi or nginx +uwisgi or nginx +pserve + supervisord

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-wsgi, pyramid, uwsgi

I have used Pyramid on Apache + mod_wsgi in the past. While looking at pyramid deployment notes came across nginx + pserve config (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html)

I know nginx has lower memory footprint and little faster than apache in serving static files.

But for a production site with lots of users (around 36K requests at any given instant), I am trying to understand which of the 3 deployment options are considered the best (or most used):

1. Apache + mod_wsgi
2. nginx + uwsgi
3. nginx + pserve + supervisord

Comment: I never compared these three options, but I used to work on a site with similar performance requirement and nginx + uwsgi worked well for that case. Also I recommend to serve static files on [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) regardless of how you serve your main application.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. For static files I do use CDN for all my projects. I have started investigating nginx + uwsgi.